# Determine if a triangle is left-facing

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, rasterizing

If you have a set of three vertices at (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3), how would you determine whether the triangle defined by these three vertices is left-facing or right-facing?

Currently, I'm taking the cross-product to determine whether the vertices are clockwise or not, and with that knowledge I can determine whether the triangle is left-facing or right-facing while I'm sorting their y-coordinates.

This works fine, but the cross-product requires five subtractions and two multiplications.

Is there perhaps some simpler, faster way to determine if a triangle is left-facing that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "left-facing"?

Comment: Left-facing would be a triangle where the (vertically) middle vertex lies to the left of the line connecting the top and bottom vertices.

Comment: what for is this used? never heard of this kind of triangle classification before.

Comment: Nit: you mean 5 subtractions, right?  Though I guess if you only care about the sign of the result you could turn that into 4 subtractions and one comparison.

Comment: You're right, it's 5 subtractions, nice catch. I've corrected that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would depend on the cost of a floating point operation visavi the cost of a conditional statement (with the added cost of clearing the instruction pipeline half of the time).

My gut feeling is that your current solution is probably a fairly good one.

Answer (score 0):

I see it like this:

1. find 2 points with min and max Y coordinate

   - if any two points have the same Y coordinate
   - then you have to chose one with X coordinate closer to the other Y min/max point
2. test the 3.th  points x coordinate

   - if it is less then any other point it is Left facing
   - if it is bigger then any other point it is Left facing

[image: triangle facing]

[Note]

- this implementation requires several `if` states
- which can be slower then to solve this by cross product ...
- even if it has less operations

if your triangles are with defined winding (always CW or CCW)

- triangle has A,B,C points
- compute count of positive and negative dy of lines like this:

  ```
  int p=0,n=0;
  if (B.y-A.y>=0) p++; else n++;
  if (C.y-B.y>=0) p++; else n++;
  if (A.y-C.y>=0) p++; else n++;
  ```
- now for CW
- `if (p<n) left_facing; else right_facing;`
- for CCW it is inegated ...

Comment: If the x-coordinate of the third vertex is between the x-coordinates of vertex 1 and 2, then you need additional calculations.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I know what you mean but is the facing even defined in such case? btw your answer concludes the same as mine see notes :)

Comment: Yes, the facing is defined. It is facing left if the third vertex is left of the side between vertex 1 and vertex 2. **Example:** (0, 0), (2, 5), (1, 3) is facing left while (0, 0), (2, 5), (1, 2) is facing right.